# Avoid writing same else statement in nested if/else

Tags: go

How do I avoid having to write the `else` statement twice in nested if/else statements?

```
func GetPortFromEnvironment(name string, defaultPort int32) int32 {
    var port int32
    if env := os.Getenv("SERVICE_PORT"); env != "" {
        if _port, err := strconv.ParseInt(env, 10, 32); err != nil {
            port = int32(_port)
        } else {
            port = defaultPort
        }
    } else {
        port = defaultPort
    }
    return port
}
```

Comment: flat is better than nested.  You can write both if statements into a single `if` with an `and` (or its equivalent in go language. wait, why am i here? *goes back to python*), and then you just have 1 if statement left. Also, in this example, you can return the port value early as well for the same effect.

Comment: I guess the question is how do I join two different conditionals?

Comment: Google says `&&` is the logical `and` in GO. I personally dont know this language im afraid, someone would have to confirm the same. Try using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll avoid using if which includes an optional statement:

```
if statement; condition {  
}
```

and using simple if with:

```
func GetPortFromEnvironment(name string, defaultPort int32) int32 {
    env := os.Getenv("SERVICE_PORT")

    // no env value. return defaultPort
    if env == "" {
      return defaultPort
    }

    // there's env value.
    port, err := strconv.ParseInt(env, 10, 32)
    if err != nil {

       // Unable to parse port. Fallback to default.
       return defaultPort
    }

    return int32(port)
}
```